# Edge length font size

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to change part of source code inside blender which determines the edge length font size?
I know, the scale of the interface can be changed, but this also changes the size of the other elements.
Thank you for Your advice.

[image]

Comment: "*Is it possible to change part of source code inside blender which ....*" Yes, Blender is open source. Whether or not it is trivial or worth your trouble is entirely another matter

Comment: For me this is important because I use edges to describe dimensions on models, it's faster for me than using Interactive Ruler tool.
The question is how can I find the right part of the code?

Comment: "*The question is how can I find the right part of the code?*" Then you should rephrase it as such, at the moment it is not clear.

Comment: I hoped that there was a numeric parameter in the code, which determines the font size in the 3d window, I understand that without programming experience I will not be able to do anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you only need the font size of the measurements to be bigger, you could use the included addon **Measurelt** which gives you a degree of customization on the font side.

[image]